# Loop over all the <dd> tags and extract specefic information via Mechanize/Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I know the basic things of accessing a website and so (I just started learning yesterday), however I want to extract now. I checked out many tutorials of Mechanize/Nokogiri but each of them had a different way  of doing things which made me confused. I want a direct bold way of how to do this:

I have this website: [http://openie.allenai.org/sentences/rel=contains&arg2=antioxidant&title=Green+tea](http://openie.allenai.org/sentences/?rel=contains&arg2=antioxidant&title=Green%20tea)

and I want to extract certain things in a structured way. If I inspect the element of this webpage and go to the body, I see so many `<dd>..</dd>`'s under the `<dl class="dl-horizontal">`. Each one of them has an `<a>` part which contains a href. I would like to extract this href and the bold parts of the text ex `<b>green tea</b>`.

I created a simple structure:

`info = Struct.new(:ObjectID, :SourceID)` thus from each of these `<dd>` will add the bold text to the object id and the href to the source id.

This is the start of the code I have, just retrieval no extraction:

```
agent = Mechanize.new { |agent| agent.user_agent_alias = "Windows Chrome" }
html = agent.get('http://openie.allenai.org/sentences/?rel=contains&arg2=antioxidant&title=Green+tea').body
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

The other thing is that I am confused about whether to use Nokogiri directly or through Mechanize. The problem is that there isn't enough documentation provided by Mechanize so I was thinking of using it separately.

For now I would like to know how to loop through these and extract the info.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you post the HTML parsing code you've attempted already?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't ask us to decipher a complete HTML page. Instead, summarize the HTML to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate your question. URLs rot and become useless but a snippet of the HTML in your question will remain usable.

Comment: When using Mechanize, it's never necessary to do `html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)`. Mechanize already has a Nokogiri DOM you can access directly. Doing it twice only wastes memory and CPU. See "[Scraping Data](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html#label-Scraping+Data)"

Comment: @theTinMan the thing is that I either use Nokogiri separately or use what Mechanize provided of Nokogiri. The second option doesnt have enoug documentation I guess. For me to understand the concept I need the method and an example provided as well.

Comment: Mechanize uses *all* of Nokogiri so all of Nokogiri's documentation and Q&A applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could parse the bold text and href attribute from the anchor elements you describe:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://openie.allenai.org/sentences/?rel=contains&arg2=antioxidant&title=Green%20tea'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.xpath('//dd/*/a').each do |a|
  text = a.xpath('.//b').map {|b| b.text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip}
  href = a['href']
  puts "OK: text=#{text.inspect}, href=#{href.inspect}"
end

# OK: text=["Green tea", "many antioxidants"], href="http://www.talbottteas.com/category_s/55.htm"
# OK: text=["Green tea", "potent antioxidants"], href="http://www.skin-care-experts.com/tag/best-skin-care/page/4"
# OK: text=["Green tea", "potent antioxidants"], href="http://www.specialitybrand.com/news/view/207.html"
```

In a nutshell, this solution uses XPath in two places:

1. Initially to find every `a` element underneath each `dd` element.
2. Then to find each `b` element inside of the `a`s in #1 above.

The final trick is cleaning up the text within the "b" elements into something presentable, of course, you might want it to look different somehow.

Comment: Thank you @maerics ! May I ask a few questions though: the * in '//dd/*/a' represents everything in between those two tags? Also from inspecting the element, I can see that there are two bold texts inside each sentence, How did you diffrentiate between them? Finally can you please give me the doc from where you learned the syntax! Thankss again!

Comment: @Sarahcartenz: yes `*` means "any element".  The bold elements are listed in sequence (`.//b` means all "b" tags anywhere below the current node) and the text of each one is processed by cleaning up whitespace; as such the "text" variable is an array of strings.  Try searching the web for things like "xpath tutorial" to learn more; it's a large topic in the XML ecosystem.

Comment: You can also use css, which I imagine most people are more familiar with. The css equivalent of `//dd/*/a` is `dd a`

Comment: @maerics according to the syntax I tried doing the same thing with with a different page: `doc2 = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://openie.allenai.org/search?arg1=&rel=contains&arg2=antioxidant&corpora='))

test = doc2.xpath('//body/*/div[@id="result-content"]/div[@class="tabbable tabs-left"]/li[@class="visible-phone"]/a').each do |x|
 puts x['href']
end` However it puts nothing for some reason, do you know whats the error?

Comment: I want to enter the body and go to the first `li` visible phone under those sections and get the link.